# selenium is waiting for too long time when object is not found not returning anything in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have written a sample code in selenium using python language and i encountered with some problem didn't get any solution

in the web, and my problem is in selenium i have kept one validation if object is available then go to next line other wise get out

from there, but selenium is keep on waiting for that object if the object is not present other wise it is returning true value and

executing fine..my requirement is if the object is not available get out from there and return false..

i have written code like this

### Type:1:

```
try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("DateOfBirthD")
        elementfound=element.is_displayed()
        if elementfound==True:
            print "element found"
        else:
            print "element not found"
except:
         print "no element"
```

### Type:2:

```
try:
     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "DateOfBirthD")))
     #do something

except:
          print "element not found"
```

In the above two types if the element is found it is working fine and going to next line 
but if the element is not found it is waiting for long time till the element is found as we know there is no element

please find me a solution to how to validate the objects in selenium

Comment: In the Python bindings, when declaring a `WebdriverWait` instance, the second argument is an `integer` in `seconds`, not `milliseconds` like in `Java`. As such, you're asking to wait up to 2000 seconds for the element to be present on the DOM. If it is never present, it will wait that entire time - about 30mins. I'd suggest changing that argument to something around 20 seconds instead.

Comment: it worked by giving less time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of time that you want it to wait is specified in seconds. In your case, you are telling it to wait 2000 seconds before continuing.

You can read about it at the official docs: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp